# Position and ScrollView in screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

> Q1
> I’ve two question about swift, I tried to position the StickerRow content so that it was displayed starting from the edge of the screen or to fit on the screen instead of being centered, how do you advise me to proceed?[Scheme position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su5nV.png)

```
 var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List (categories.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
                StickerRow(categoryName: "\(key) Slot".uppercased(), stickers: self.categories[key]!)
                    .frame(height:320)
                    .padding(.top)
                    .padding(.bottom)
             }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Lorem ipsum"))
        }
    }
}
```

> Q2
> For tis second question I would like to make these two slots scrollable horizontally, but they come out vertically. [ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsPBX.png)

```
var body: some View {
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    
    Text(self.categoryName)
        .font(.title)
    
    ScrollView{
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            ForEach (stickers, id: \.name) { sticker in
                
                        StickerItem(sticker: sticker)
                        .frame(width: 100)
                        .padding(.trailing, 30)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
Thanks for Help!

Comment: For the second question, please read the documentation or google. Here is one article https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-using-scrollview

Comment: Great! I followed these instructions and works for both of codes. Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.